# I had never been here before or I have never been here before?

Tags: tense, sentence-structure, present-perfect, past-perfect

> I had never been here before?
>
> I have never been here before?

Which one from these two is correct? The one in present perfect or the other in past perfect?

I came across both.

The "before" in the end confuses, so i think i have to use past perfect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The *before* isn't relevant to the tense. It can be there in any case, just its meaning is relative to the 'time' of the sentence.

The construction "never been here **before**" means that the person speaking is talking about a time they were *here* for the first time. If it's in present perfect, it means they are there for the first time *now*. If it's in the past perfect, it means they are talking about a time in the past when they were there for the first time.